# Highchart plotband is not rectangular?

Tags: highcharts

For some reason in Highstock, adding a plotband doesn't draw a rectangular band!?

There are two charts on their own y-axis but sharing the same x-axis.

I'm adding the plotbands dynamically after the chart has loaded:

```
}, function(chart) { // on complete

    var i = 0;

    data.exits.forEach(function(time) {

        i++;

        chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
            from: time[0]*1000,
            to: time[1]*1000,
            label: {
                text: "Exit"
            },
            color: '#000',
            id: 'plot-band-'+i
        });
    });
});
```

[image: Weirdband]

Comment: Things to look for: Is your data sorted in ascending chronological order? Console errors?

Comment: This is a new addition to a otherwise working chart. No new console errors.

I checked the chronological ordering, and it is possible that there are some rare points mixed in that are not in proper chronological order. Although in that case it would mean that some data packages would might be 100% in proper order, and I'm seeing this skewed band in with all the data so far... An average data package has about 10k points.

Comment: It's bug in 1.3.10 version of Highstock. Try: http://github.highcharts.com/master/highstock.js - it's upcoming release.

Comment: Great - thanks for the info Pawel! Actually we were using the latest release, and that was updated today to 2.0.0 which fixed this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accorcing to Pawel Fus, this was a bug in 1.3.10 version of Highstock. The current newest version 2.0.0 fixed this bug.